# Which eradicated viruses still have remaining stockpiles?

Tags: virology, infectious-diseases

Other than smallpox, I'm curious to know if there are any other stockpiles of eradicated or nearly eradicated viruses, and if so where are they located?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about biology but about social policy.

Comment: If you ask this question on the history or politics stack exchange sites, I'll answer it for you ;)

Comment: again, I don't think this information would be publicly available in many cases because rogue nations involved in developing biological weapons would likely keep their research a closely guarded secret.

Comment: There are only two eradicated viruses, and one "nearly eradicated", and all have known stocks. For the purpose of this question, it's completely irrelevant to talk about "rogue nations"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only two viruses have been eliminated in the wild to date: Smallpox (humans) and Rinderpeste (cattle). As the question notes, smallpox stocks still exist. So do Rinderpeste stocks; see [Identifying and Reducing Remaining Stocks of Rinderpest Virus](https://wwwnc.cdc.gov/eid/article/21/12/15-0227_article), which is from 2015, but has no indication that the stocks were to be destroyed in the near future.

The only virus that is "nearly eradicated" is poliovirus (human) and there are still many stocks of polio, although organizations are working on reducing their number ("[Toward Eliminating Poliovirus—In the Lab](https://www.the-scientist.com/?articles.view/articleNo/44481/title/Toward-Eliminating-Poliovirus-In-the-Lab/)).

Comment: Thank you so much for this information--it's exactly what I was looking for for my med school presentation.  Do you also know if there are any established stockpiles for other, non-viral infectious agents that are becoming progressively eradicated (e.g. Plasmodium falciparum, Dracunculus medinensis, Treponema pallidum pertenue)?